# Tensor Products of bimodules over commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose that $  R $ and $ S $ are commutative rings with identity, $ R  \subset S $, $ 1 _{R} = 1_{S}           $, $ M $ is a $ (S,R)$-bimodule, $ N $ is a  $ (R, S)$-bimodule, $ T =     M       \otimes_{R}  N   $, $  (T, *) $ be the left $ S $ module structure on $ T $ via $ s * ( m \otimes n ) =        sm     \otimes n $, $  (T,   \cdot )  $ be the right      $ S $-module structure on $ T $ via $   ( m  \otimes n )  \cdot s   =   m \otimes  ns $. Is it possible that the $ (T,   * ) \neq   ( T ,  \cdot ) $ in the sense that $  s  *         (  m  \otimes  n )    \neq        ( m     \otimes n )   \cdot s                           $ in general.

P.S. I asked this question after working through Example 5 of the third set of examples in section 10.4 of *Abstract Algebra* by *Dummit and Foote*, p. 369. As far as my working shows, this cannot happen if we take $    R =  \mathbb{Z} $, $ S = \mathbb{Q} $, $ M = V $ a vector space with left multiplication and $ N = W $ a vector space with right multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for the two module structures to be the same and, in general, they are not.

For an extreme example, consider a ring $R$ with a non-identity endomorphism $\sigma:R\to R$ and let

- $S=R$,
- $M=R$ with the obvious right $R$-module structure and the left $R$-module structure given by $r\cdot m=\sigma(r)m$.
- $N=R$ with the obvious left and right $R$-module structures.

If $\xi=1\otimes1\in M\otimes_RN$, then $r \cdot \xi = \sigma(r)\otimes 1$ and $\xi\cdot r=1\otimes r=r\otimes 1$, and these two things are different as soon as $r\neq\sigma(r)$. For example, if $\sigma(r)=0$, this is clear.

Comment: Isn't $ \sigma  =     id $, because I want $  \sigma ( 1_{R} ) = 1_{R} $ and then, $ \sigma( r) =  r   \sigma ( 1_{R} ) =   r $? 


P.S. I want unital modules, as I am not interested in pathologies.

Comment: $\sigma$ is an endomorphism **of rings**

Comment: Oh, right. You don't need algebra homomorphism to achieve this.

Comment: Is it necessary the condition $R\subset S$ to define product of two bi-modules?